# A problem about gradient estimates for Poisson's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, poissons-equation

During studying Gilbarg-Trudinger's Elliptic PDEs of $2^{nd}$ order, I've been confused about an derivation of the estimates inequality for a long time. In sec. 3.4 Gradient Estimates for Poisson's Equation, they derived the estimate (3.16) by the following inequalities: 
$d_{x}|Du(x)|\leq C(\sup_{\partial Q}|u|+d^2 \sup_{Q}|f|)\leq C(\sup_{\Omega}|u|+\sup_{\Omega}\ d^2_y|f(y)|) \tag{1}$ 
where $\Omega$ is any region (open and connected) in $\Bbb{R}^{n},\ d_{x}=\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$ and $d=d_{x}/\sqrt{n}$. 
The former parts in the second and third formula is clear. Since $Q\subset\Omega$ and $u$ is continuous on $\bar{\Omega}$, $\sup_{\partial Q}|u|=\sup_{Q}|u|\leq \sup_{\Omega}|u|$. 
But it seems no evidence that the formula holds in the latter parts, i.e. 
$Cd^2 \sup_{Q}|f|\leq C\sup_{\Omega}\ d^2_y|f(y)| \tag{2}$ 
Since $d^2 \sup_{Q}|f|=\frac{d_x^2}{n} \sup_{Q}|f|$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ can be absorbed into the second $C$ in $(2)$. Therefore, the real matter is whether the following inequality holds: 
$d_x^2 \sup_{Q}|f|\leq \sup_{\Omega}\ d^2_y|f(y)| \tag{3}$
For a simple counter example, by taking $x\in \Bbb{R}^n,\ \Omega=\{x+w: |w_i|<d_0,\ w=(w_1,...,w_n)\}$, we then get $Q=\Omega,\ d=d_0$. Since for any $y\in\Omega,\ d_x=d_0\geq d_y$, we have $d_x^2 \sup_{Q}|f|=d_0^2\sup_{\Omega}|f|\geq d_0^2|f(y)|\geq d_y^2|f(y)|$.  
Therefore, $d_x^2 \sup_{Q}|f|\geq \sup_{\Omega}d_y^2|f(y)|$. And I get an inversed ordering of $(3)$. 
I know I can't say $(1)$ is wrong if $(3)$ is wrong. But $(3)$ is the way I try to understand the proof of $(1)$. Can anyone explain why $(1)$ is correct which is written in the Gilbarg-Trudinger's book. Many thanks.

Comment: Formatting tip: enclose important equations with double dollar signs, i.e `$$\text{important equation}$$`. Also to get the supremum to format nicer use `\sup`.

Comment: I'm guessing $Du$ is the Jacobian of $u$?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for help. $Du=(u_{x_1}, u_{x_2},...,u_{x_n})$. I think $|Du|=\sqrt{u_{x_1}^2+u_{x_2}^2+...+u_{x_n}^2}$.

Comment: Ok, so the gradient in this case. I will try to analyze the problem once I finish my coursework for the day.

Comment: OK, got it. Many Thanks.

Comment: What is $f$? Does $u$ solve the equation $\nabla^2 u=f$?

Comment: Yes. And $f$ is continuous on the domain of definition. Sorry, I don't pose the contexts of the question. I recommend you to have the book, Gilbarg-Trudinger's PDE of 2nd order, to get better understand what the contexts of the question is.

Comment: I don't have the book unfortunately.

Comment: OK. Let $Q=\{x+w: |w_i|<d,\ w=(w_1,...,w_n)\}$ and $u\in C^2(Q)\bigcap C^0(\bar{Q})$ be the solution of Poisson equation $\Delta u=f$, then the book demonstrates a subtle bound estimate: 
$|D_{i}u(x)|\leq \frac{n}{d}\sup_{\partial Q}|u|+\frac{d}{2}\sup_Q|f| \tag{3.15}$. And $(3.16)$ is $\sup_{\Omega}d_x|Du(x)|\leq C(sup_{\Omega}|u|+\sup_{\Omega}d_x^2|f(x)|)$
which is derived from $(3.15)$ and $(1)$ in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The authers apparently skiped some details here. You can first take $d=d_{x}/2\sqrt{n}$ so that the distance to the boundary is uniformly bounded below by some quantity that is comparable to $d$ in there.